# CUPS causes printer to click and doesn't print

Tags: debian, printing, cups, raspberry-pi

I'm suffering a strange problem with my Cannon **iP4850** when trying to use CUPS on a Raspberry Pi (this is not RPi specific, please do not vote to move it).

When I plug the printer into my Laptop (OSX) or my Desktop W7 it identifies as a iP4800 and prints perfectly.

So I plug it into the Pi (running debian), set it up in CUPS enable sharing and can now see the iP4800 series shared on the network.

**However** if I print to it (using AirPrint etc...); the file gets to CUPS safely (shows in the queue) but when it tries to print the printer clicks (like a loud thunk) 3/4 times and then gives in, with a double amber flashing light. In cups it shows as job completed.

Do you know why using the pi and cups would cause what appears to be a hardware fault and what I can do to fix the problem or to provide further debug info?

Thanks for your time!

```
Description:    Canon iP4800 series
Location:   Lounge
Driver: Canon PIXMA iP4800 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.9 (color, 2-sided printing)
Connection: usb://Canon/iP4800%20series?serial=2239B2
```

Note: I've tried deleting and re-adding the printer to the Laptop, Desktop and PI and the results are always the same

---

Log for plugging in printer and printing (attempting to) something until the printer turned off again

```
pi@pezpi /var/log $ dmesg
[ 7284.176336] usb 1-1.2: new high speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[ 7284.279703] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04a9, idProduct=10d5
[ 7284.279750] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 7284.279771] usb 1-1.2: Product: iP4800 series
[ 7284.279786] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Canon
[ 7284.279800] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 2239B2
```

---

Setting cups to **verbose**:

Change loglevel in cupsd.conf to debug (or debug2)

```
pi@pezpi /var/log $ sudo vim /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
pi@pezpi /var/log $ sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
[ ok ] Restarting Common Unix Printing System: cupsd.
pi@pezpi /var/log $
```

---

Log from $ /var/log/cups/error_log is at http://pastebin.com/7VZMRMrG (too large to post here)

The log contains - in order (deleted the log and then did the beneath)

- Restarting the cups server
- Attempting to print a test page x2
- Printing from 192.168.1.90 via AirPrint
- Printing from 192.168.1.90 via Network Print
- Turning the printer off and on again

Comment: Check system log (`dmesg`) and CUPS log(?). Look for a way to make CUPS verbose.

Comment: Have uploaded a full copy of the log

Comment: Line #15 of the CUPS error log looks ominous.  Did you install anykind of CUPS driver or cupswrapper file for this Canon printer?  Or is it installed as a "raw" print device?

Comment: Maybe you need to install a driver like this? http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0040246.asp?model=

Comment: I installed the PPD file (compiled from source) taken from the Cannon website for the iP4850 so I'm not sure it's the drivers. As far as I'm aware I haven't installed any CUPS specific driver (taken from http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0010893.asp)

Comment: Seem like you need to bring up the Printer administration/congiguration GUI, like this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Gnome2.26-printing-dialogue.png  Under the printer's properties, you should be able to determine if it's a raw device or if a driver has been installed.  The symptoms seem to indicate that the printer does not have a driver and/or a proper filter.  Not sure, but the PPD file might be for LPR usage rather than CUPS.  And your syslog doesn't show *usblp* registration for that device!?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a GUI installed, is there a way to determine this through ssh?

Comment: `lpoptions` seems to return the driver name in *printer-make-and-model=* for the default printer.  Another interface is the CUPS web server on port 631, but I can only access the `localhost:631/printers/`, and cannot get to a remote host (even after tweaking `/etc/hosts.allow`)

Comment: I now have a stranger problem, I've fixed file "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstocanonij" not available: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

Just replying as I had a very similar problem with my Canon PIXMA iP4300 printer: CUPS reported that jobs were being printer whereas they weren't. In the end, the solution I stumbled across was to go to 'Set Default Printer Options' in CUPS and change the colour model to CMYK (it was set to RGB as default). This solved it! Maybe it works for you too.